# What am I doing wrong with my object functions?

Tags: python

So my goal is to create a quiz.
I first went about it with global variables but despite using return and global indicator I couldn't get it to work so I went to classes and objects.
Below is a small sample with an answer to the first question.

```
print('Hello, Welcome to the what bender are you test!')
print('Answer the questions one at a time in order and in lower case. When youre done 
       answering all of them type Done to get your results. Ready? Lets go!')

print('What is your favorite rainbow color? Indigo and Violet are in here too.')
print('Do you know your blood type? Just answer yes or no ^^')
print('What is your Hogwarts House?')
print('Out of these four animals which do you prefer? Deer, Ram, Longhorn 
      Hummingbird')


class Benders():
    def __init__(self,points = 0):
    self.points = points



Firebender = Benders()
Airbenders = Benders()
Waterbenders = Benders()
Earthbenders = Benders()
    

def red():
       setattr(Firebender.Points,1)
```

I dont know what to do, I can't leave red in the class functions or people cant type in the answer to change the attribute. I've also tried putting the class in the parenthesis to clarify for python. Please help

Answer (score 1):

`setattr` takes the object and the attribute name as separate arguments:

```
setattr(Firebender, 'points', 1)
```

but it's simpler to just write

```
Firebender.points = 1
```

`setattr` is more useful when the name of the attribute you want to change is stored in a variable, and so you can't use the dot notation:

```
attribute = "points"
# Firebender.attribute = 1  # sets attribute, not points
setattr(Firebender, attribute, 1)  # OK
```

Comment: I suspect they meant to use `Firebender.points` instead of `.Points`, though

Comment: Good ... point. *ducks*

Comment: I accidentally mistyped that . In firebender and didnt realize it but that was a happy accident because now I know I'm allowed to do that ^^. I have another question though, will it break everything if I write it Firebender.points = Firebender.points + 1?

Comment: No, that's exactly how you would write it (although you can also simplify it to `Firebender.points += 1`. I would recommend reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) some more to clarify these points (there I go again) of syntax.

Comment: I did do it but according to vars it did not work and Im not sure why, I even copied your code directly to make sure I didnt mistype.
Do you think you could direct me to the tutorial page you think would help? I tried scrounging through the class pages already and found nothing but maybe I'm missing something